# Search in parent relationship with the database driver

Tags: laravel-scout

Let's say you have this relationship: `users` x `cats`. Each user can have many cats (a "one-to-many" relationship):

```php
class Cat extends Model 
{
    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Both models (users and cats) have a `name` field.

Let's say we want to get all cats with `bob` in their names, using Laravel's Scout.

The standard solution is to add this to the `Cat.php` model:

```php
// Cat.php
use Searchable;

/**
  * Get the indexable data array for the model.
  *
  * @return array
  */
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
    ];
}
```

And we search with `Cat::search('bob')->get()`.

### The problem

The above solution works well, but what if we want to search in the relationship's fields?

What if you want to get cats owned by people with `bob` in their names?

If you add this to the "Cat" model:

```php
// Cat.php
use Searchable;

/**
  * Get the indexable data array for the model.
  *
  * @return array
  */
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'users.name' => '', // no need to return `$this->user->name` as the database engine only uses the array keys
    ];
}
```

It won't work. You will get this exception when running `Cat::search('bob')->get()`:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.name' in 'where clause'

SQL: select `cats`.* from `cats` where (`cats`.`name` like %bob% or `users`.`name` like %bob%)
```

Clearly, the SQL is missing the `users` table. But how to add it? Doing a `Cat::join(...)->search('bob')` will throw an exception, same for `Cat::search(...)->join(...)`.

The question is: **How to search in the parent attributes?** And by "parent" I mean the "belongsTo" model.

Answer (score 0):

The `query` method allows for modifing the search query. Use it to inject a `join` clause:

```php
Cat::search('bob')->query(function ($builder) {
    $builder->select('cats.*')->join('users', 'cats.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
})->get();
```

This generates the proper query:

```sql
SELECT `cats`.*
FROM `cats` 
INNER JOIN `users` on `cats`.`genre_id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE (`cats`.`name` LIKE '%bob%' or `users`.`name` LIKE '%bob%') 
ORDER BY `id` desc
```

---

EDIT: Automatically adds the JOIN clause to all searches:

If you want to search with just `Cat::search('bob')->get()`, without having to write `->join(...)` on every call:

```php
// Cat.php
/**
 * Overrides the "search" method to inject a `join` to the relationships.
 */
use Searchable {
    Searchable::search as parentSearch;
}

/**
 * Perform a search against the model's indexed data.
 *
 * @param  string  $query
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return \Laravel\Scout\Builder
 */
public static function search($query = '', $callback = null)
{
    return static::parentSearch($query, $callback)->query(function ($builder) {
        $builder->select('cats.*')->join('users', 'cats.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
    });
}
```